# field started with % in struct in Specman

Tags: struct, specman, e, field-names

I am new to Specman, just don't know what the "%" prefix of a field in struct mean?
for example, the codes below.

```
struct packet_s like any_sequence_item {
  %addr  : uint(bits: 2);
  %data  : list of byte;
  ...
};
```

What's the difference if we removed the "%"?

Thanks.

Comment: These are "physical" fields meaning they will be considered when doing pack-operations on an instance of the struct. Please consult the Cadence Specman documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

https://support1.cadence.com/api/CosWeb/TechPubDocViewerCosLite/fc3d80347c2f211300916bfa538b076651c4801891f9ea50632a49a087be22bdb643c4344882eaa17a4f8911ffeae7ae4b135bd5c651280b198cdf0fd45653fbb58f41e83ef196b05bc14ce64bdbe65f0cf4d2da8a027d933155221675c881fba3d831ea161e8d008c25cb280d677e9451f5aa8a0451a1ef2b0946a87c48f62860c3700f80457adc49c9b0edc1cd04118c01e7fcfcf36e1518240c3117007cd3886d869848346b919165453ac5e2d13c/Docs/sn_eref/sn_eref21.09/sn_eref.pdf

To get all support\docs related Specman you should first register to their website

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).